# Backbone.js - Saving data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm trying to sync my Backbone.js app to the server. 
I'll note that I overrided my sync in the collection to use jsonp:

```
window.Project = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize:function () {

    },

    urlRoot:"http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects",

    defaults:{
        "id":null,
        "completion_state":"0",
        "last_update_datetime":"0"

    }
});


window.ProjectList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Project,

    url:"http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects/",

    sync: function(method, model, options) {             
        options.dataType = 'jsonp';
        options.url="http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects/?    format=jsonp&callback=moshe";           
        //options.contentType='application/json-p';
        options.error=this.errorr;
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    },

    parse: function(response) {
         return response.objects;
  }


});
```

The problem is, while "fetch" is working just fine, when I try to "create" a new model to the collection - I get this network error:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not using your `jsonp` configuration in the `Collection.create()` This is because the Collection delegates in the `Model.save()` to *create* elements.

Check the [Collection.create() code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/355c48011a68284b69754aa5a4e0ddabb789b20d/backbone.js#L804).

You should override the `Project.sync()` as well.